# C# - need to know when variable goes out of scope

Tags: c#, scope, garbage-collection

I have some C++ code that I'm trying to port to C#.  The original author had a cool indented debugging C++ class that works like this:

```
void a()
{
   indented_debug id;
   id.trace("I'm in A");
}
void b()
{
   indented_debug id;
   id.trace("I'm in B");
   a();
}
void e()
{
   a();
}
void d()
{
   e();
}
void c()
{
   indented_debug id;
   id.trace("I'm in C");
   a();
   b();
   {
      indented_debug id2;
      id2.trace("I'm still in C");
      d();
   }
}
```

And what you see in the output is this:

```
I'm in C
   I'm in A
   I'm in B
      I'm in A
   I'm still in C
      I'm in A
```

Which makes it really easy to see not only the order in which functions are being called, but who's calling whom.  The indentation (which is the key thing here) is automatically handled by the construction & destruction of the "indented_debug" objects.  Every time an "indented_debug" object is constructed, it increments a "how much shall I indent" counter; every time an "indented_debug" object is destructed, it decrements that counter.  It's this automatic calculation of the indentation that is the key to this class.

Of course, C# doesn't like this at all.  C# goes out of its way to make sure that you are absolutely completely prevented from knowing when a variable has gone out of scope.  And yes, I know how garbage collection works, and I do like it, but it seems like Microsoft could have given us a function IsThisObjectUnreachable() or something like that.  Or, an attribute keyword [RefCount] that means "Do reference counting on this object instead of garbage collection".

I can't find any way to know enough about an object to know whether it's gone out of scope, is there some clever way to provide this same functionality in C#?

I should also throw in this design restriction: I would really rather not wrap all of my functions in "using (indented_debug id = new id) { }", the idea is to have this debugging capability with as little impact on the code and its readability is possible.

[Added later]

It's a little tricky, adding to the original question later like this, but I need to write some code and can't do that in comments.

The StackTrace method is oh-so-close to the solution I was looking for, let me explain what it looks like.

```
public class indented_debug
{
   static int minFrame = 999;
   static void trace(string text)
   {
        StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
        StackFrame[] frames = stackTrace.GetFrames();

        if (frames.Length < minFrame)
            minFrame = frames.Length;

        String indent = new String(' ', (frames.Length - minFrame) * 3);
        Debug.WriteLine(indent + text);
   }
}
```

This is extra cool because you don't even need to construct an object of type indented_debug - the indentation is completely controlled by how deep in the stack you are.  The drawback, of course, is that in my example when c() calls d(), there are two extra stack frames in there where there is no tracing happening, so the indentation would be more than is required.  Rob has suggested a way around this by adding a custom attribute to the methods, which does solve that problem (I didn't include his code in my example, you can read it below).

But there is another issue, the StackTrace concept doesn't allow for additional indentation inside a function (like I have in my original c() function).  I was thinking that the number of times where the code has extra indents inside a function is quite small, so it's probably acceptable to add the "using" block in those cases.  That means the C# code looks like this:

```
[IndentLog]
void a()
{
   indented_debug.trace("I'm in A");
}
[IndentLog]
void b()
{
   indented_debug.trace("I'm in B");
   a();
}
void e()
{
   a();
}
void d()
{
   e();
}
[IndentLog]
void c()
{
   indented_debug.trace("I'm in C");
   a();
   b();
   using (indented_debug id = new indented_debug())
   {
      indented_debug.trace("I'm still in C");
      d();
   }
}
```

And then the object 'id' is constructed & finalized in a deterministic way, and I can create a data structure where I associate 'id' with the current stack frame when it constructs, and de-associate it when it finalizes.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the scoping that's giving you trouble?

Comment: First thing is that you're confusing and mixing scope with lifetime. A variable has scope, an object has a lifetime. (A variable goes out of scope at the end of the enclosing block.)

Comment: You're question is about variables going out of scope, but your code is about logging behaviour. Can you clarify in what sense you care that variables are going out of scope?

Comment: Are you willing to switch to using `using` statements and a class that implements `IDisposable`?

Comment: In C++ it is important to *manually* deallocate memory. In C#, this is done by the GC. To explain how it works and why it isn't just a memory leak with a pattern name, you'll want to read Richter CLR via C#, particularly the chapter on garbage collection. You can force early garbage collection, but interfering with the GC usually makes perf and memory usage worse.

Comment: The key thing (apparently this wasn't clear) is that in the C++ code, it's the objects constructing & destructing (as they go out of scope) that provides the indentation information.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, but I do understand the difference between scope and lifetime.  It's the basic problem at the core of my question.  In C++ scope and lifetime are pretty much the same, in C# they are very much not.  When the C++ "indented_debug" object is created, it increments the "how much shall I indent my output" counter, and when it goes out of scope (and thus its lifetime is over), it decrements the "how much shall I indent my output" counter.

Comment: You can't do it based on constructors and finalizers, because in C# you have no way of knowing when a finalizer will run - it is up to the garbage collector. The best way would be using `IDisposable` classes as @Damien_The_Unbeliever suggests, as that is the only sensible mechanism for getting deterministic behaviour.

Comment: For people looking at this discussion later in time: I went back at this point and added more text to explain how important the indentation was.  Hopefully that clears up some of the initial confusion.

Comment: You want two things to happen in two different places, but you only want to write the code in one place. You want "}" to have a side effect that is both important and invisible. If those are things you want, then C# is not the language for you. If you want two things to happen in two different places, then **write code in those two different places**. If you want something to happen before the } then **write code before the }**.

Comment: Moreover, consider how your proposed indented logger works or, more accurately, fails to work in the presence of asynchronous code. The notion that control passes nicely from outer scope to inner scope and back to outer scope is no longer true.

Comment: I agree with the comment about asynchronous code, and you are quite correct that this method would not work in that case.  For me, that's not an issue, the functions being debugged are all in one thread.  I should have included that as a design parameter.

Comment: But I'm not sure I agree about what you are calling "side effects".  Every language has these side effects, it's just a question of what they are.  In C++, when you hit the '}' indicating end of scope, local variables are destructed.  In C#, in the same situation, local variables are marked in some way that the garbage collector eventually notices they are unreachable.  I would also say that your command about "if you want something to happen before the } then write code before the }" is violated in a using() block - when the final '}' is hit, I don't have to manually call object.finalize()

Comment: No, in C#, the lifetime of an object can be much *shorter* than the lexical scope. Hitting the `}` is meaningless. A variable only keeps an object alive if it will be *read* from again in the future.

Comment: Thanks Damien, I did not know that.  Are we guaranteed though that in a using() block, the variable in the using() is kept alive until the end of the scope?  Or could the variable be marked "unreachable" long before it hits the final '}'?

Comment: Yes, if you go down the `using` block route, you are guaranteed, because the end of the `using` block does have to read the variable in order to call `Dispose` on it.

Comment: What you are guaranteed is what the C# specification says you are guaranteed, which is that a `using` is a short way of writing a try-finally. Now, the question of what the jitter is permitted to do in this context is a complex one. See my series of articles called "Everything You Know is Wrong" on why you cannot make good predictions of when finalizers run.  A properly written disposable object will not have these problems. It's just that writing them properly is very difficult.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: You are actually not guaranteed that. Suppose you are disposing a 4 byte struct and the compiler has resolved the call to Dispose to a method that does not use the reference to this. The jitter is permitted to *enregister* the struct and re-use that register before the dispose. Remember, the jitter doesn't work on the level of variables, it works on the level of stack slots and registers when computing the roots of the live set. Now, this scenario is bizarre and unrealistic; a finalizable struct with an empty Dispose is broken in many ways.

Comment: @EricLippert - thanks. I'm always amazed at the layers it's possible to go to with seemingly simple concepts and taking things to bizarre extremes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> as I said in my last paragraph it's not the desired behavior. Inserting a couple of lines at the top of a function is much less impactful than wrapping the whole function in a "using" block. Makes people much less nervous about the impact the debugging code is having on the overall function.

*from a comment from OP.*

Now, in C# 8, you can use *Using declarations*.

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace SO_36796820
{
    public class OutOfScopeEvent
    {
        public string MethodName { get; set; }
        public int StackLevel { get; set; }
    }

    public delegate void NotifyInScope(OutOfScopeEvent obj);
    public delegate void NotifyOutOfScope(OutOfScopeEvent obj);
    
    public class OutOfScopeToken : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly string _methodName;
        public event NotifyOutOfScope NotifyOutOfScope;
        private readonly int _stackLevel;
        
        public OutOfScopeToken(string methodName = "", int stackLevel = 0)
        {
            _methodName = methodName;
            _stackLevel = stackLevel;
        }
        
        public void Dispose()
        {
            NotifyOutOfScope?.Invoke(new OutOfScopeEvent() { MethodName = _methodName, StackLevel = _stackLevel });
        }
    }

    public class OutOfScope : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly OutOfScopeToken _outOfScopeToken;
        
        public event NotifyOutOfScope NotifyOutOfScope;
        public event NotifyInScope NotifyInScope;

        private int _stackLevel = 0;
        
        public OutOfScope()
        {
            NotifyOutOfScope += OnOutOfScope;
        }

        public OutOfScopeToken GetToken([CallerMemberName] string methodName = nameof(GetToken))
        {
            NotifyInScope?.Invoke(new OutOfScopeEvent()
            {
                MethodName = methodName,
                StackLevel = _stackLevel
            });
            var outOfScopeToken = new OutOfScopeToken(methodName, _stackLevel);
            outOfScopeToken.NotifyOutOfScope += NotifyOutOfScope;
            _stackLevel++;

            return outOfScopeToken;
        }

        private void OnOutOfScope(OutOfScopeEvent obj)
        {
            _stackLevel--;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _outOfScopeToken?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class Program
{
    private static OutOfScope _outOfScope;
    static void a()
    {
        using var v = _outOfScope.GetToken();
        b();
        c();
    }
  
    static void b()
    {
        using var v = _outOfScope.GetToken();
    }

    static void c()
    {
        using var v = _outOfScope.GetToken();
        d();
    }

    static void d()
    {
        using var v = _outOfScope.GetToken();
    }
        
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _outOfScope = new OutOfScope();
        _outOfScope.NotifyOutOfScope += OutOfScope;
        _outOfScope.NotifyInScope += InScope;
        a();
    }

    private static void InScope(OutOfScopeEvent obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new String('\t', obj.StackLevel) + " I'm in " + obj.MethodName);
    }

    private static void OutOfScope(OutOfScopeEvent obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new String('\t', obj.StackLevel) + " I'm out of " + obj.MethodName);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 I'm in a
         I'm in b
         I'm out of b
         I'm in c
                 I'm in d
                 I'm out of d
         I'm out of c
 I'm out of a
```

Answer (score 4):

The `IDisposable` interface is the mechanism to use in C# when you need to do something deterministically when an object is no longer needed.  So it's not as streamlined a C++ but it's certainly possible to do something similar:

```
void a()
{
   using(var id = new IndentedDebug())
   {
       id.trace("I'm in A");
   }
}
void b()
{
   using(var id = new IndentedDebug())
   {
       id.trace("I'm in B");
       a();
   }
}
```

And add reference counting to the `IndentedDebug.Dispose` method.

There may be better ways to do it with AOP or other patterns, but it is *possible* to do something when a variable goes out of scope.

Comment: Yes, and if I have to go this way I will, but as I said in my last paragraph it's not the desired behavior.  Inserting a couple of lines at the top of a function is much less impactful than wrapping the whole function in a "using" block.  Makes people much less nervous about the impact the debugging code is having on the overall function.

Comment: @BettyCrokker A using statement is probably the best/most reliable you're going to get. I wouldn't assume too many people would be confused about the impact of the logger (especially if they were to check the code). StackExchange actually does something *very* similar, but for profiling: http://miniprofiler.com/ which uses `using` statements to manage hierarchy.

Answer (score 3):

Based on all the great input from this community, here's what I'm going with (at least for now).  Sorry if the Hungarian notation offends you, I spent a lot of time in MFC-land and still kind of like it.

```
internal class IndentFrame
{
    public string m_type, m_function;
    public bool m_bOutput = false;
    public int m_nExtra = 0;

    public IndentFrame(StackFrame frame)
    {
        m_type = frame.GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name;
        m_function = frame.GetMethod().ToString();
    }

    public bool Matches(StackFrame frame)
    {
        return (m_type == frame.GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name)
            && (m_function == frame.GetMethod().ToString());
    }
}

public class IndentDebug : IDisposable
{
    internal static List<IndentFrame> m_frames = new List<IndentFrame>();

    public static void WriteLine(string text)
    {
        UpdateFrames();
        // Remember that this frame produced output.
        m_frames[m_frames.Count - 1].m_bOutput = true;
        // How much indent?
        int nIndent = 0;
        foreach (IndentFrame frame in m_frames)
            nIndent += (frame.m_bOutput ? 1 : 0) + frame.m_nExtra;
        String indent = new String(' ', (nIndent - 1) * 3);
        Debug.WriteLine(indent + text);
    }
    internal static void UpdateFrames()
    {
        StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
        StackFrame[] frames = stackTrace.GetFrames();

        // frames[] are ordered such that the current frame is at [0] but we
        // want the topmost frame in [0]
        Array.Reverse(frames);

        // Remove any obsolete frames from our list
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < Math.Min(m_frames.Count, frames.Length); i++)
        {
            if (frames[i].GetMethod().DeclaringType == typeof(IndentDebug))
                break;
            if (!m_frames[i].Matches(frames[i]))
                break;
        }
        if (i < m_frames.Count)
            m_frames.RemoveRange(i, m_frames.Count - i);
        // Add any new frames
        while (m_frames.Count < frames.Length)
        {
            if (frames[m_frames.Count].GetMethod().DeclaringType == typeof(IndentDebug))
                break;
            IndentFrame frame = new IndentFrame(frames[m_frames.Count]);
            m_frames.Add(frame);
        }
    }

    internal static void UpdateIndent(int add)
    {
        UpdateFrames();
        m_frames[m_frames.Count - 1].m_nExtra += add;
    }

    public IndentDebug(string text)
    {
        IndentDebug.UpdateIndent(1);
        IndentDebug.WriteLine(text);
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        IndentDebug.UpdateIndent(-1);
    }
}
```

}

This comes quite close to my original desires, in most cases you can just add one line to a function (without requiring an additional custom property):

```
void a()
{
   IndentDebug.WriteLine("I'm in A");
}
```

But if you want extra indentation inside a function, you can get it by adding a "using" statement:

```
void c()
{
   IndentDebug.WriteLine("I'm in C");
   a();
   b();
   using (IndentDebug id = new IndentDebug("I'm still in C"))
   {
      d();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is some code I knocked up in LinqPad, which does what you want:

```
void Main()
{
    c();
}

void a()
{
    using(var id = new IndentedDebug())
    {
        id.Trace("I'm in A");
    }
}

void b()
{
    using(var id = new IndentedDebug())
    {
        id.Trace("I'm in B");
        a();
    }
}

void e()
{
    a();
}

void d()
{
    e();
}

void c()
{
    using(var id = new IndentedDebug())
    {
        id.Trace("I'm in C");
        a();
        b();
        {
            using(var id2 = new IndentedDebug())
            {
                id2.Trace("I'm still in C");
                d();
            }
        }
    }
}

class IndentedDebug : IDisposable
{
    const int indentSize = 2;
    const char indentChar = ' ';
    static int indentLevel = 0;

    private string _indentSpaces;

    public IndentedDebug()
    {
        _indentSpaces = new string(indentChar, indentSize * indentLevel);
        ++indentLevel;
    }

    public void Trace(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", _indentSpaces, message);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        --indentLevel;
    }
}
```

So your code doesn't quite look the same, but on the other hand, it's not doing any "magic" either - the code itself shows you when the indented debug ends.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you have a look at the StackTrace class

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

It tells you exactly what methods were called to get to your current point and lots of other stuff.

If you still have access to a member variable then technically its still in scope unless you have manually descoped it or disposed it. So if you're aware of the variable in code then its not out of scope.

Comment: Yup, I did play with that a little, it's not bad except that you can't have different indentation levels within a single function (like I do inside my c() function).  I looked into StackFrame, it will tell me the current line number, but I didn't see any way to use that to know what the scope of the current indented_debug object is.

Answer (score -1):

There is a very clever way to do this:

1. Global variables are in scope for the entire instantiate class.
2. Method variables are in scope for the entire method
3. Any variables in brackets are in scope inside that bracket.

Aside from knowing how scope works in the first place, your "id.trace()" method looks more like a console output.  You could just as easily replace it with Console.WriteLine("I'm in ..."); and get the same results.

Comment: I think they're looking to discover this information *in code*, from within the *same* code. Not by inspecting source.

Comment: Yes, id.trace() can go to console or file or whatever output device you chose.  But no, Console.WriteLine() does not give you the indentation that depends on how many stack levels it took to get to your current location.  And yes, I know how scope works, the problem is that the variables don't know what their scope is, so can't provide the indentation information.  The indentation is the key feature that I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm not even certain why this type of scope debugging is relevant.

Comment: Can you tell me another way to look at a complex series of function calls and see the overall flow of when things were called and why?  printf() debugging is really old, but sometimes it's the best tool in the tool belt.

Comment: are you talking about during debug or while the program is running?  Because during debug you can just break and look at the callstack.